# Tensorflow 2.0 small image dataset warning

Tags: image, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am learning image classification using TensorFlow 2.0, while implementing it I am getting this warning:

> tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 11280 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

Here are the dataset sizes and model data:

```
total training mango images : 752
total validation mango images : 288

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=752,
                              epochs=15,
                              validation_steps=288)
```

I have also used image augmentation techniques to make the model efficient. but still, the warning interrupts the training and the model remains overfit.

[Here is the link to my full model in github](https://github.com/sonichandni/image-classification-TF2.0/blob/master/mango_classification.ipynb)

kindly help me out!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you get your error at 24th step and that `batch_size` is 32, I suppose the problem is that your 24th batch has only 16 images. You may drop these images so your dataset will align with batch size of 32, or change `batch_size` to 16.

By the way, I suspect that you're using `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` wrong - "steps" means the number of batches, not the number of samples. FYI

Comment: Sorry if it was't entirely clear from my answer - could you set `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` to the amount of batches that you actually have? I.e. 47 for training and 18 for validation?

Comment: Thanks! I have tried with different combinations of sizes and it worked, But it still overfit model..

Comment: I'm afraid you don't have enough data. However, you can try to perform transfer learning on one of the `tf.keras.applications` pretrained models, ResNet50V2 is a good starting point.

Comment: Sure. Thank you :)

Comment: If possible can you please share some good reference to how to set all these parameters according to the dataset size? It would be a great help.

Comment: Check out [TF official guide for working with images](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#train_the_model)

Comment: Yeah. Following the same

Comment: @ Vladimir Sotnikov can you please tell me how you calculated 47 and 18 values? which you have mentioned on 1st comment.